# okhttp3 ошибка при отправке get

Tags: запрос, get

Уже достаточно продолжительное время не могу найти ошибку. Отправляю get запрос при помощи okhttp3

```
    public class Get {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run(String url, Callback callback) {

        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
}


    obj = "http://" + server + "/box/fbscript.php?k=" + id + "&f=" + this.selectedItem;
    System.out.println(obj);
    Get test = new Get();

    test.run(obj,
            new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    //todo work with response, parse and etc...
                    System.out.println("Ok");
                }
            });
```

Код просто входить в onFailure. Ссылку проверял, формируется правильно. Никак не могу понять где ошибка

Comment: Выведите стек-трейс и посмотрите его.

Comment: Подскажите, как именно это сделать

Comment: В `onFailure` необходимо добавить `e.printstacktrace()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted